# How to handle Blobs in Google App Engine alternatively to Cloud Storage and BlobStore API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

The BlobStore API is marked as 'superseded' also limited to Limits to 32 MB.
The Google Cloud Storage is a vendor lock-in.

Is there a way to upload blobs with a 3rd part lib
In Google App Engine (not flexible / managed-vms) for example JClouds

And how would one bypass the 60 Seconds request limit that causes DeadlineExceededException?

To enhance the question;
Security is an issue, it would be preferably to run every request trough the application, so also blob uploads. Which makes the 60 seconds an issue.
The seperate uploadUrl is an option, but i do not wish to use BlobStore or Cloud Storage, but is there a generic way to handle things like this in GAE?

Comment: Vendor lock-in??? It takes a few lines of code to upload the files, and you can move them out at any time. If you do your code right, it will take you an hour to switch to AWS or a different provider.

Comment: Agreed vendor lock in issue might be trivial but i would still prefer a abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

32MB is not a limitation of the BlobStore, but rather request playloads that go to your GAE app. You can upload larger files to both Cloud Storage and the BlobStore by creating a temporary URL for the user to submit the file to, which does not go through your ap, but rather goes directly to the storage service. You can find documentation about that for blobstore [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob).  I don't personally use Cloud Storage, so I don't the a documentation link handy.

You can certainly use any other service in a similar way, but I'm afraid I can't explain how other than to say "consult their documentation". I know that's not a great answer to your question, but maybe insight into how it works with Google's products will help you understand how to use a 3rd party as well.

As for the 60 second request limit: since your upload requests cannot go through your server anyway, this is a non-issue. The 60 second limit only applies to requests made directly to your app.

Comment: this answer points in the right direction. for GCS signed url sample see https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-signed-url  which isnt obvious in the docs because google only implemented it in the xml api.